# Putting images in one frame, click on image, have that image open in a different frame

Tags: javascript, html, image, hyperlink, gallery

I am trying to set up an image gallery that will allow an image from the middle frame to open open in the main frame. I have it set up right now to allow people to scroll the images down one frame. If I can get the image to open in another frame so people don't have to scroll back up to the top, that would be my end goal.

Thank you in advance for any and all help, this is what I have so far.

```
<script>
function myFunction(imgs) {
  var expandImg = document.getElementById("expandedImg");
  var imgText = document.getElementById("imgtext");
  expandImg.src = imgs.src;
  imgText.innerHTML = imgs.alt;
  expandImg.parentElement.style.display = "block";
}
</script>

<a href="01.png" target="middle" onclick="myFunction(this);"> <img src="01.png" style="width:150px; height:150px;"> </a> <br>
```

The index page containing the frames info.

```
<FRAMESET ROWS="65px,*" frameborder="0">
   <FRAME SRC="top.html" NAME=top scrolling="no">
<frameset cols="150,150,700" frameborder="0">
   <frame src="content.html" name="content" scrolling="yes">
   <frame src="middle.html" name="middle" scrolling="yes">
   <frame src="main.html" name="main" scrolling="no">
</frameset>
</frameset>
```

Comment: where's the "frame"?

Comment: And what goes wrong with your current implementation? I.e. what is your question?

Comment: I can not get the image to open in the other frame. From middle frame to main frame.

Comment: [Framesets](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/frameset) and frames have been deprecated for over ten years ago. You really should move to HTML5.

Comment: That said, there's a lot going on in your script. `this` in the inline event handler refers to the `a` element (which doesn't have `alt` and `src` properties). Also, it's not clear, which frames all the referred elements and the script are placed to. A frame creates its own browsing context (~ `window` object), `document` in the current browsing context can't refer to another window. You can get a reference to the window in the frames via `frames` collection of the top page, something like `top.frames['middle'].document` would give you `document` inside the frame named "middle".